# heroku node app exits after idling

Tags: node.js, heroku

i have a node app hosted on heroku.  works fine, but once the app starts idling after 30 minutes, the app changes from up to down, and exits with status 0.

```
2016-08-16T00:02:28.554960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-08-16T00:35:02.601620+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2016-08-16T00:35:02.602105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2016-08-16T00:35:05.902125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2016-08-16T00:35:06.827968+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Could it be something in the code, or do i just need to keep it from idling?

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If this is on the free tier then this is expected behavior, it's the price you pay for free. It should restart on the next web request to it, but the latest terms for the free tier don't let you keep it on 24/7 even if that many requests come in.

Free tier is best for while you're prototyping.  Once you're serving customers you should either go paid or move to a different host.

Comment: Thanks @Paul.  So if I switch to the Hobby plan, I should be good?  The issue is that my node app has cron jobs, and once the app goes down, the jobs won't run.

Comment: That should do it, though Heroku would probably you to move things around a bit and have your crib jobs on worker dynos and use their scheduler thing, but I've never tried that myself.

Comment: I initially thought it was a postgres issue OR heroku issue somehow because my postgres DB kept getting deleted. Now I know why, when the app restarts (from state being down and then coming up), I had a property in the config file that was wiping the data. Further, I am trying an app that pings heroku apps every 30 minutes so it doesn't sleep, anyone know about: https://kaffeine.herokuapp.com ?

Comment: Free app running time quota exhausted

Comment: @Paul are there any host that are running 24/7 for free? And thanks for your answer. I can see Heroku free tier shuts down after 30 minutes. The Hobby version is always on and cost 7$ /month

Comment: I haven't done the research in quite a while (my answer here is nearly 5 years old) but AWS, Google Cloud and Azure all have free tiers that you can check out.  They have a slightly different model than Heroku so depending on how tightly you coupled to Heroku you might have to make a few changes but they're all three good and stable.