# Node app running on cPanel hosting shuts down after 30 minutes idle

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I have a REST api node app.
Once its running on localhost, it runs until I stop the dev debugging, no errors.
I moved it over to my cPanel hosting, installed a node app.
It starts up the same as localhost.
But after 30 minutes being idle, it shuts down.
The next request after this, restarts the app.
There are no crash or errors in the log, just the restarting messages.

I know this is default behaviour for free hosting, like [Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965035/heroku-node-app-exits-after-idling) but I'm paying for this hosting package.

Does anyone know...
Is this default behaviour for cPanel hosted node apps, or is my app causing this (using too much memory or cpu for example?
Is there any settings that can be edited to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/), cPanel uses something called Phusion Passenger to run Node.js. In turn, [Passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/nginx/#passenger_pool_idle_time) show a default "idle time" of 5 minutes and a default of `passenger_min_instances = 1`. No idea if cPanel changes the defaults, or if the hosting provider did. I would recommend contacting the hosting provider about the issue in any case, and asking about these options specifically - they may be able to help or tune the service for you.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I contacted my hosting and they initially thought it would not switch off, then found out it did.  Everyone seems to be learning as we go :-). after reading supplied docs I will forward this information to them.

Comment: More info: The hosting company tried to change the idle time to 0, making it so the app would stay running, but each time they did it the app would timeout, and the conclusion was cPanel was overriding it somehow. They also said that these settings would be overwritten next time there was a system update.  So the moral of the story is shared hosting node app will timeout and stop, and if that is a problem for the app, dedicated hosting should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

The startup time for a node app depends on what it's doing.  A rest-api could be in the milliseconds, whereas a small Ai app loading a corpus or training a dataset (which mine was) could end up being 30 seconds plus.  However the quantity of users did not warrant a dedicated server, so the work-around was to call the endpoint using a CRON, keeping the app alive.

Not perfect, but this type of thing may be useful if you are using aws lambda, which calls a 3rd party service, and which charges based on time taken.  Every millisecond counts.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue today and I found a better solution than the accepted answer. You can solve this by adding a cronjob that visits your node app every x minutes using a simple `curl` command.

This will prevent your node app from timing out. You can do this easily in CPanel:

[image: CPanel advanced section]

[image: Cronjob example]

Comment: If you had read the last message in this conversation, it tells you I used CRON and it has been running like that for the past 2 years.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. My bad. That is definitely the solution until today.